# set gRPC hostname to other asside from localhost

Tags: certificate, grpc, hostname

I would like to change the hostname of the grpc service that i created.

Usually i can access the service through https://localhost:5001 and i want to change that into something else like https://apiservice.bml.com:5001. I am using a certificate with this format *.bml.com and i was able to use it in the service see code below.

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(server =>
                    {
                        server.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                            listenOptions.UseHttps("bml.pfx", "testabc");
                        });
                    });
```

thanks.